# Ito's formula for this stochastic differential - please explain this step?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

[image]

Referring to those two lines, can someone please explain how those results were obtained?

My understanding is, the following formula is being referenced:

$$dV_t = dV(S_t,t) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}S_t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}dt+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}(dS_t)^2$$

But I am not sure how to apply it, to obtain the result:

$$dV_t =  2W_tdW$$

For instance, how do we get a $-dt$ term and a $\frac{1}{2} * 2dt$ and a $2W_tdW$ term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $$ V = W_t^2 - t$$
hence (written with $t$ and $x$, where we plug in $S_t = W_t$ for $x$), we have
$$ V(x,t) = x^2 - t$$
Now 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} &= -1\\
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} &= 2x\\
  \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} &= 2
\end{align*}
Hence (note that $S_t = W_t$)
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(W_t, t) &= -1\\
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(W_t, t) &= 2W_t\\
  \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}(W_t, t) &= 2
\end{align*}

Ito gives 
$$\tag{$*$} dV = 2W_t dW_t - 1 \cdot dt + \frac 12 \cdot 2 \cdot (dW_t)^2 $$
(note that you have a typo in your Ito, it should read 
$$ dV = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \color{red}{d}S_t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt + \frac 12\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial x^2}(dS_t)^2 $$
Continuing with $(*)$, as $(dW_t)^2 = dt$, we end up with 
$$ dV = 2W_tdW_t - dt + dt = 2W_tdW_t. $$